# Regexp word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

Regexp word boundary.

According the [Regular_Expressions guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), `\b` matches a word boundary, such as a space, a newline character, punctuation character or end of string.

I am trying to change the following string from.

```
"
    abc
"
```

to

```
"abc"
```

I did try the following, but it does not work.
Any ideas?

```
"  abc  ".replace(/\b/,"");
```

Comment: Look at the answers provided below, those can be more suitable for you.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps someone with an MDN account may want to correct it?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Edited entry. I've reviewed the whole table, and added anchors to it, so that it's easier to reference to a specific escape character in the documentation - see https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary

Answer (score 3):

That description of word boundaries is badly written (which happens a lot, unfortunately).  You'll find a much better reference [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

A word boundary is a zero-width assertion: it doesn't consume any characters, it merely asserts that a condition is true.  In this case, it asserts that the current position is either followed by a word character and not preceded by one, or preceded by a word character and not followed by one.

If you want to match anything that's not a word character, use `\W` (note the capital `W`).  But you really only need to match whitespace, which is `\s`:

```
"  abc  ".replace(/\s+/, "");
```

If you're trying to do a traditional trim operation, you need to use anchors to make sure you only match whitespace at the very beginning or end of the string:

```
"  abc  ".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, "");
```

Comment: I've been struggling with why \b works in some cases where my non-capturing groups fail. Your statement that a word boundary is a zero-width assertion brought home what was going on more than anything I've read in the last few days. Thanks for stating the uniqueness so succinctly and clarifying what was at play

Answer (score 0):

`\b` maches only boundary without spaces, selecting place between space and first/last letter.

use this:

```
//fulltrim replaces all new lines with space and reduces doubled spaces
String.prototype.fulltrim=function(){return this.replace(/(?:(?:^|\n)\s+|\s+(?:$|\n))/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' ');}

//just trim spaces from begging and ending of string
String.prototype.trim=function(){return this.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');};
```

usage

```
"    ssss   ".fulltrim();
"    
   ssss 
".fulltrim();
```

Some browsers have implemented `trim` method.

Answer (score 0):

`\b` itself does not match character, it matches **position**. Just like `^` and `$`.

```
"\n\t   \n  hello world \t  \n\n".replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
// return "hello world"
```